# integral representation of first kind Bessel function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, bessel-functions, trigonometric-integrals

i have some problem with the integral representation of first kind bessel function $J_n(x)$

i have to proof this formula:

$$J{_n}(x)=\frac{i^{-n}}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(n\phi-x\cos\phi)}d\phi\tag{1}$$

To proof that equation, i have considered the generating function for first kind Bessel function $J_n$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$:

\begin{equation}
e^{\frac{1}{2}x(t-\frac{1}{t})}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty J_k(x) t^k
\end{equation}
Assuming $t=e^{-i\varphi}$ and multiplying both members of latter equation for $e^{in\varphi}$, we have:
\begin{equation}
e^{in\varphi}e^{\frac{1}{2}x\big(e^{-i\varphi}-\frac{1}{e^{-i\varphi}}\big)}=e^{in\varphi}e^{-ix\big(\frac{e^{i\varphi}-e^{-i\varphi}}{2i}\big)}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty J_k(x)e^{-ik\varphi}e^{in\varphi}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e^{in\varphi}e^{-ix\sin\varphi}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty J_k(x)e^{i(n-k)\varphi}
\end{equation}
integrating from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, follows:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{in\varphi}e^{-ix\sin\varphi} d\varphi=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty J_k(x)e^{i(n-k)\varphi} d\varphi=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty J_k(x)\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(n-k)\varphi} d\varphi
\end{equation}
Since it results:
\begin{equation}\tag{*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  e^{i (n-k)\theta}d\theta =
\begin{cases}
2\pi&\text{per }n=k\\
0&\text{per }n\neq k
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
From previous exprension:
\begin{equation}
J_n(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i(n\varphi-x\sin\varphi)}d\varphi
\end{equation}

Now we can substitutes $\varphi=\phi+\pi/2$, so the previous expression becames:

\begin{equation}
J_n(x)=\frac{e^{in\frac{\pi}{2}}}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(n\phi-x\cos\phi)}d\phi=\frac{i^{n}}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(n\phi-x\cos\phi)}d\phi \tag{2}
\end{equation}

But now i can proced to obtain the (1)? Is it wrong since there's $i^{-n}$ and instead of $i^{n}$? becouse i have seen the Jacobi-Anger expansion, and using it, i obtain the latter relation (2)

Comment: @metamorphy That substitution does not take care of the differing integration limits.

Comment: @MarkViola: I see - in fact a mistake is made in the OP (integration over $\theta$).

Comment: @MarcoToni: To fix the mistake, integrate over $(-\pi,\pi)$. And it just remains to substitute $\varphi=\phi+\pi/2$ (with the limits unchanged because of $2\pi$-periodicity).

Comment: @metamorphy I have made the correction you suggested, but i have the doubt that there's a mistake in the equation (1) since i have looked to the jacobi-anger expansion and i obtain also in this case the equation (2). Should be $i^n$ instead of $^{-n}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: [The mistake I noted above was in $(\text{*})$.] Yes, I think $(2)$ is correct, not $(1)$ ([see also](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9)).

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3839137).